# ¿Como llenar un GridView desde un fragmento en Android?

Tags: android, android-fragment

Tengo un Problema estube revisando un tutorial de como llenar un GridView en Android, pero eso lo llenaban desde un Activity, lo he provado y si me funciona perfectamente, pero al momento de ponerlo en un Fragment es donde me bota un error...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como pueden ver no es problema de otra cosa solo que no sé que poner en context. Ayudenme Saludos.

Comment: el contexto lo obtienes con `getActivity()`

Comment: Hola @juan no es una buena practica colocar imagen en lugar de código por favor si puedes cambia tu imagen por el código.

Comment: Si amigo, eso tambien lo he probado igual me sigue saliendo ese error.

Comment: Juan, bienvenido a SOes. Asi como indica Yoel, aqui existen muchas personas que pueden ayudarte y si incluyes el codigo en tu pregunta en vez de una captura de pantalla, te podran ayudar mucho mejor. Te invito a [edit] tu pregunta para cambiar esto. Saludos!